# Couldn't understand the error message: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '(' Constructor Survey (address _owner) payable public

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0+;
contract Survey {
    /* Events */
     event SurveyInitialized(address indexed owner, uint indexed surveyReward);

    /* Contract State */
    address public owner;
    address private factory;

    Constructor Survey(address _owner) payable public {
        (_owner != address(0));
        (msg.value > 0);
        owner = _owner;
        factory = msg.sender;
        emit SurveyInitialized(owner, msg.value);
    }
}
```

the error :

> browser/checkbalance.sol:12:20: ParserError: Expected ';' but got '('
>   Constructor Survey (address _owner) payable public

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to put any name after `constructor`. Just write it as :

```
constructor (address _owner) payable public
```

Also change your pragma to:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

for better results.